# HTML/CSS Text not indenting inside boxes

Tags: html, css

This web page is to animate boxes and show some text details, however when the box flips i can't indent my text inside the box

I want to make the text size smaller for my box which is getting flipped over.
However the text does not get affected by align.
I want to add all the text inside the box and they should not cross the box.

https://codepen.io/srinabh/pen/XBKQdm

```css
flexbox{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}
.panels{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}

.panels li{
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left
}

.panels li div{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.panels div.back{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e40000, #f07611);
 transform: rotateY(90deg);

  font-family: Cabin;
  font-size: 1.4707843137254901vw;
  color: #3d4250;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
.panel div.front{
  background: white;  
  font-family: Cabin;
  font-size: 1.9607843137254901vw;
  color: #3d4250;
   position: relative;
}

/*// ANIMATION STYLES //*/

.panels li:hover div.front{
  animation: twirl 0.2s ease-in forwards;
}

.panels li:hover div.back{
  animation: twirl 0.2s 0.2s ease-in forwards reverse;  
}
@keyframes twirl{
  0%{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="panels flexbox">
      <li>
        <div class="front">Sense of Purpose</div>
        <div class="back"><h6>Sense of purpose</h6>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #9126f4">Get to</div>
        <div class="back">The chopper</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #21bf3b">foo</div>
        <div class="back">bar</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #c3333d">tempus</div>
        <div class="back" >fugit</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #c3333d">html</div>
        <div class="back">rocks</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #21bf3b">A</div>
        <div class="back">B</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #9126f4">Super</div>
        <div class="back" >Mariokart</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="front" style="background: #267df4">j</div>
        <div class="back">Query</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing line height will resolve text overlapping issue.

```
.panels li div{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*line-height: 0;*/
  cursor: pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

And add height on divs.

```
.panels div.back{
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e40000, #f07611);
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        height: 18px;
        font-family: Cabin;
        /* font-size: 1.4707843137254901vw;*/
        color: #3d4250;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top:0;
      }
      .panel div.front{
        background: white;  
        font-family: Cabin;
        /*font-size: 1.9607843137254901vw;*/
         color: #3d4250;
          position: relative;
      }
```

Comment: The text runs down the box and the size of the box becomes bigger, any way we can fix that?

Comment: Hi @Srinabh , working on it, edits answer in few minutes.

Comment: why remove the font size (in vw) ?

Comment: @Srinabh, removed font size to set text inside box.

Comment: can we edit something to start the text to appear from the top of the table rather than the middle?

Comment: Working with align you can do it now.

Comment: added it another question, vertical align doesent seem to work